# When is a job too small for meetings?

Tags: contracts, difficult-client, price, client-support, billing

As a graphic designer, not all of the jobs I take on are that big. A lot of the time it may just be a couple days work.

But I find a lot of clients want to meet up to discuss the project in detail. I'm happy to meet up and talk through it, but if they expect me to travel far (I don't drive) then it doesn't make much sense to me due to the amount of my time that it will consume.

Would it come across as unprofessional to tell a client that I'm not willing to travel to meet them because the job is too small i.e. 1–2 days work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I like this question: I struggled with the exact same thing with meetings in general. Clients one hour away asking me to join in on a meeting. I usually ended up spending an afternoon with 2 hours travel and 2 hours meeting.

So these days, I'll try Skype first. 
If the client doesn't want Skype I'll explain that I will need to invoice the time because the size of the project (and my quote) normally don't include face to face meetings. 
Most clients will then decide Skype isn't so bad after all, others understand my predicament and are willing to pay for my time.

Answer (score 2):

No, do not decline them unless you do not work on it, you don't like it and so on.

Simply ask a client if he is wiling to cover your travelling costs and that you will charge time spent on meeting with him.

After all, in the meeting you are not drinking coffee and talk about the purpose of life, but you actually work, right?

If the client accepts, you are happy as you are not travelling in vain. If he declines, then you are happy again as you never wanted to travel on the first place.